# Is there any reason to add pagination to sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, pagination

Let's say I have the following site structure:

```
root
  category1
    item1
    item2
    ....
    item99
  category2
    item101
    item102
    ....
    item199
  ...
```

Each category page contain pagination to allow reasonable amount of items on each page. From my point of view I'd keep the sitemap structure as I mentioned above (with out any care of pagination used on categories pages). Is that right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The pagination would be unnecessary as the sitemap will tell Google where to find all of the item pages.